# Silverlight Chart

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, charts

I would like to create an application that shows the history of disk usage.

I have already create a backend for geting data and now I would like to show this data in a line chart like this:

[image: chart sample]

As you can see, I get date (DateTime) and usage (int) foreach disk.

My question:

**Which silverlight component/tools should I use, to show the charts?**

I'm looking for a free solution that is easy to understand/use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few options:

- [Visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com/), fast, high performance chart
- [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) a Microsoft chart, but a bit slow
- [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/), high performance chart with great looks and interactivity

Comment: Is it possible to summarize the blog post here? We like answers to be able to stand alone.

Comment: Hi Michael, It was old story but Visifire is the fastest chart now. The images says Visifire is 3 to 4x faster than Visiblox! Blog Link: http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/12/02/fast-silverlight-charts/

Comment: Considering that the 'fastest chart' title is subjective and changes all the time, I have deleted all reference to it. People can make up their own minds!

Answer (score 3):

My recommendations is to use [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/). Its easy to use and has simple XAML structure. Visifire does most of the work automatically like placing AxisXLabels in multiple rows, AxisLabels in angled form, and auto skipping of those labels if there is an overlap. Apart from it there are other great exciting features provided by Visifire like Indicator, Zooming etc.

Last but not the least, it is the high performance charting component.

http://www.visifire.com/high_performance_silverlight_examples.php

[image]

For more info, please check out the exhaustive documentation.

http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_gauges_documentation.php

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

see [this](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202) and [this](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) for more details, sample code and sample charts